# How to show $T$ is not one-one and $T$ is not ont0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Suppose $V$ is the space of all $n \times n$ matrices with real elements. Define $T : V \to  V$ by $$T (A) = AB − BA,\; A \in V,$$  where $B \in V$ is a fixed
>   matrix. Show that for any $B \in V$,
>
> (a) $T$ is linear;
>
> (b) $T$ is not one-one;
>
> (c) $T$ is not onto.

Trial: Part (a): $$\begin{align}T(aA_1+bA_2)&=(aA_1+bA_2)B-B(aA_1+bA_2)\\&=a(A_1B-BA_1)+B(A_2B-BA_2)\\&=aT(A_1)+bT(A_2)\end{align}$$ So $T$ is linear. Please help with the others.

Comment: hint for (c): for any matrix $A$, you have $\operatorname{tr}(T(A))=0$.

Comment: @yohBS: Please explain why $tr(T(A))=0$ implies $T$ is not onto?

Comment: because all matrices with non-zero trace cannot be in the image of $T$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(b) What is $T(I)$? What is $T(0)$?

(c) What is $\operatorname{tr}(T(A))$? What is $\operatorname{tr}(I)$?

Comment: I understand part (a). Is $tr(T(A))=tr(AB)-tr(BA)=0$?. I know that $tr(I)=n$.Please explain how it shows $T$ is not onto.

Comment: @Argha If $T$ is onto, then $I=T(A)$ for some $A$. Take traces on both sides, you reach a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The $n\times n$ identity matrix $I$ is a non-zero element of $V$. Where does $T$ send it? What does that tell you about injectivity? What does that tell you about the rank of $T$?

Answer (score 1):

Part (b): For $A=B$ you obtain $T(A)=0$.

Comment: That will just prove (b) for one instance of $B$. You need to prove it for _all_ possible $B$.

Comment: @Arthur: No, Boris's answer is fine; *for any given choice of $B$*, letting $A=B$ will give $T(A)=0$.

Comment: @ZevChonoles I am not having a good day today. I misread $A=B$ as $B=A$.